# Prevent duplicate updates

Tags: ios, firebase, duplicates

2 users can view each others changes/updates to an object that is stored at a single location on backend. Client side observes when backend updates occur, to stay in sync. Current user should see their own updates immediately, so I update before sending request to backend.

This means that if current user makes an update, changes will be made locally, then sent to backend, which will fire an event, causing current user client to update again unnecessarily. What approach can I take to prevent this?

Comment: How big a problem is this for you? Does it cause a noticeable effect on the current user's UI?

Comment: In reality, probably not too big of a problem. Just seems inefficient and something to prevent if possible.

Comment: If from the user's perspective it's not noticeable, then I guess it's a trade-off between (i) that degree of inefficiency and (ii) the extra code / database complexity of trying to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accomplished with adding a field to your current database record which stores the objectId of the user that sends the update so server side send to all users excluding the value of objectId which is the user that send the update